# Where to put global Hash variable in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a place to  keep last request time for user and don't want to use database for that

Comment: I don't think I understand the question well enough to know if I have an answer - why do you need last request time, how reliable need the information be, why don't you want to use the database? (To start with!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use memcache for this.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do this user-wise, and don't mind losing it between sessions, then the place to store it is a session like session[:last_request]

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy solution - you can put it as a constant in config/environment.rb

Comment: Doesn't have to be a constant, you can declare anything there. You may have an issue with multiple copies of the app giving slightly different results.

Answer (score 0):

there is an easy way (although not so elegant)

```
if Thread.main[:uuid] == nil 
  Thread.main[:uuid]=0
end
uid = Thread.main[:uuid] += 1
```